# jQuery: access dropdown menu items via Tab

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, accessibility

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu accessible via the keyboard (using only Tab, no access keys). I can't figure out how to make subitems accessible.

The desired behaviour is the following: when "item" is clicked or has the focus, display the list; when "item" loses the focus (on blur), if no "sub item" has the focus (which would mean that it has been accessed via the keyboard), hide the list.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DBdbz/

**HTML**

```
<p id="ui"><a href="#">Item</a></p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('ul').hide();

$('#ui a').on('focus', function() {
  $('ul').show();
});

$('#ui a').on('blur', function() {
  $('ul').hide();
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/DBdbz/6/ ?

To get the focus/blur to work on every browser, the only thing that is needed is a tabindex on a given element (no matter which one, see Lee's [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html)):

```
<p id="ui"><a href="#" tabindex="1">Item</a></p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here comes the JS:

```
$('ul').hide();

$('#ui a').on('focus', function() {
  $('ul').show();
});

$('#ui a').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    $('ul').addClass('tab');
  }
});

$('ul').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('ul').addClass('mouse');
});

$('ul').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('ul').removeClass('mouse').removeClass('tab');
});

$('ul li:last-child a').on('blur', function() {
  if ($('ul').hasClass('tab')) {
    $('ul').hide().removeClass('tab');
  } 
});

$('#ui a').on('blur', function() {
  if (!$('ul').is('.tab, .mouse')) {
    $('ul').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another fiddle that does the tabbing correctly. Your original fiddle didn't open the menu when I click on "Item" so I'm not sure what that means.

http://jsfiddle.net/DBdbz/4/

This code goes after yours to make the tabbing work:

```
$("ul a").on('focus', function() {
    $('ul').show();
});

$("ul a").on('blur', function() {
    $('ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I've just tested it on IE 9, Opera 12.10 and Chromium latest (my default browser is Firefox latest). My code worked everywhere but on Chromium.

Comment: Notice here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html where it points out that Chrome does not fire focus/blur events on links when a mouse is used and Safari doesn't fire them ever.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
$('ul').hide();

$('#ui a').on('focus', function() {
  $('ul').show();
});

$('#ui a').on('blur', function() {
  if ($('ul li').is(':focus').length < 1) $('ul').hide();
});
```

It only hides the ul if none of the ul's li is focused.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've already tried something similar but it doesn't work. At the very moment "#ui a" loses the blur (when your test occurs), none of the sub items have the focus yet.

Comment: well then wrap the if line in a little timeout, like this: "setTimeout(function() { if ($('ul li').... hide(); }, 20);"

Comment: It doesn't work either: the sub item does get the focus but when the function times out, the list is hidden. See http://jsfiddle.net/DBdbz/2/

Comment: okay, you have to use .is() instead of .filter(), see edit. http://jsfiddle.net/DBdbz/3/ works for me

Comment: Then the list is not hidden any more.